# Counting the number of items in a JSON array for Steam API

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, steam

I have Steam API working and functional but i want to count how many times an item is in the array so i can print how many items i have in stock.

I'm using this for Team Fortress 2 Items

This is the URL i use. I took out my API key and steam ID
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=APIKey&SteamID=Steam_ID&format=json

Its output is:

```
{
"result": {
    "status": 1,
    "num_backpack_slots": 300,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1264649944,
            "original_id": 1264649944,
            "defindex": 267,
            "level": 4,
            "quality": 5,
            "inventory": 2147483948,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 1,
            "flag_cannot_trade": true
        },
```

But there are more items then just that one.

I want to know how to count the number of items with a specific defindex and print it.

EDIT:

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayer Items/v0001/?key=&SteamID=&format=json');
$myarray = json_decode($link, true);

print $myarray['result']['items'][0]['id'];
?>
```

Comment: I see your edit, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [count](http://www.php.net/count):

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayer Items/v0001/?key=&SteamID=&format=json');
$myarray = json_decode($link, true);

echo count($myarray['result']['items']);
?>
```

EDIT:
To count ones with a specific property you'll have to loop through all of them and increment a variable:

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayer Items/v0001/?key=&SteamID=&format=json');
$myarray = json_decode($link, true);

$count = 0;
foreach($myarray['result']['items'] as $item){
    if($item['defindex'] == 267){//or whatever you're looking for
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: what if i wanted to search multiple defindex's and echo a single total of them all

Comment: You would add more checks to the if statement, separating them by `||` which means `or`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your `items` array. If you are looking for a specific `defindex` you will just tally the number of times you see that specific value.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($myarray->result->items as $item)
{
    if ($item->defindex == 5000)    // Scrap metal
    {
       $total++;
    }
}
```

If you are looking to tally each type of item, you will want to do something like:

```
$inv_array = array();
foreach ($myarray->result->items as $item)
{
    if (array_key_exists($item->defindex,$inv_array))
    {
        $inv_array[$item->defindex]++;
    }
    else
    {
        $inv_array[$item->defindex] = 1;
    }
}

var_dump($inv_array);
```

This will contain an array with a count of each unique `defindex`

The mistake you have in your code above is that you are looking at `id`. This is unique for every item in the TF2 economy AND changes with each new owner, and each new tool applied to the item.

Comment: i was printing ID just for an example